# Difference between radiometric correction at surface and at sensor in ENVI

Tags: remote-sensing, envi

I want to ask you about the difference between the radiometric correction at surface and at sensor in ENVI software, I do the two in flash and radiometric correction and the results was same image. Can you help me to understand?